# How to lock a user into his home folder in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, filesystems, user-accounts

How to lock a user into his home folder in Ubuntu?

Comment: Don't give them root access?

Answer (score 2):

You could chroot their home directory, then they would not be able to see anything below that.

Comment: configuring a [chroot jail](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/chroot-practices.html) isn't a simple (or space-efficient) process.

Comment: Any tutorial about chroot approach? @spowers

Answer (score 1):

Considering that for directories the permissions bits do the following:

- **read**: grants the ability to read the names of files in the directory.
- **write**: grants the ability to modify entries in the directory.
- **execute**: grants the ability to traverse its tree in order to access files or subdirectories.

you could change the permissions of the "others" user of the directories in the filesystem that you want to quarantine from the user.

While in theory this solution should work, I did not tested it and I can't say that there would be no problems involved.